# When I click the Home button on the android I want it to save the frame AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3

This is for the game i am doing
When I click the Home button on the android I want it to save the frame it was in and not start the game loads where it was

This results in saving the game forever but I just want it to save once and the code to load does not work

```
   import flash.net.SharedObject;

   stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, buttonPressed); 
   var stateSO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("saveState");
   if (stateSO.size > 0 && stateSO.data.lastFrame && stateSO.data.lastFrame != undefined) {
  //the shared object exists and has a valid value, so lets skip to that frame
 gotoAndPlay(stateSO.data.lastFrame);
 trace("Load Here.");
 }


 function buttonPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void{  
 if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.MENU){

 //this function runs every frame 
 function saveState(Event){       
 stateSO.flush(); //save the cookie (shared object)
 trace("Save Here.");
 return;
 }

 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, saveState);

 stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, buttonPressed);
 } 

 }
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's unnecessary code inside your keypress event handler (and other places), and you **never** actually write the value you want to save. Also, **always** format your code because a lot of errors could occur just because you cannot read clearly what your code is actually doing.

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;

var stateSO:SharedObject;

// I guess this is a frame script, lets run it
// only once to avoid the possible mess.

if (!stateSO)
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, buttonPressed);

    stateSO = SharedObject.getLocal("saveState");

    if (stateSO.data.lastFrame != undefined)
    {
        trace("Load Here.");
        gotoAndPlay(stateSO.data.lastFrame);
    }
}

function buttonPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // I hope you know what this button is.
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.MENU)
    {
        saveState();
    }
}

function saveState():void
{
    // Write current frame to the SharedObject.
    stateSO.data.lastFrame = currentFrame;
    stateSO.flush();
    trace("Save Here.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Organis

Comment: in the animate CC this work fine but when a export to apk file and put in the android then not work

Comment: the Keyboard.MENU is the Home buttton right? http://pocketnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/sgs3-home-button.jpg is the middle?

Comment: @HugoAzevedo No, I don't think so: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html